# SDL - how to render text from an alpha-only bitmap?

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to render text using SDL. Obviously SDL does not support rendering text by itself, so I went with this approach:

- load font file
- raster glyphs in the font to a bitmap
- pack all bitmaps in a large texture, forming a spritesheet of glyphs
- render text as a sequence of glyph-sprites: copy rectangles from the texture to the target

First steps are handled using FreeType library. It can generate bitmaps for many kinds of fonts and provide a lot of extra info about the glyphs. FreeType-generated bitmaps are (by default) alpha channel only. For every glyph I basically get a 2D array of A values in range 0 - 255. For simplicity reasons the MCVE below needs only SDL, I already embedded FreeType-generated bitmap in the source code.

Now, the question is: how should I manage the texture that consists of such bitmaps?

- What blending mode should I use?
- What modulation should I use?
- What should the texture be filled with? FreeType provides alpha channel only, SDL generally wants a texture of RGBA pixels. What values should I use for RGB?
- How do I draw text in specific color? I don't want to make a separate texture for each color.
- FreeType documentation says: *For optimal rendering on a screen the bitmap should be used as an alpha channel in linear blending with gamma correction*. [SDL blending mode documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureBlendMode) doesn't list anything named linear blending so I used a custom one but I'm not sure if I got it right.
- I'm not sure if I got some of SDL calls right as some of them are poorly documented (I already know that locking with empty rectangles crashes on Direct3D), especially how to copy data using `SDL_LockTexture`.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <SDL.h>

constexpr unsigned char pixels[] = {
  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  30,  33,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1, 169, 255, 155,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  83, 255, 255, 229,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 189, 233, 255, 255,  60,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0,   0,  33, 254,  83, 250, 255, 148,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0,   0, 129, 227,   2, 181, 255, 232,   3,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0,   2, 224, 138,   0,  94, 255, 255,  66,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0,  68, 255,  48,   0,  15, 248, 255, 153,   0,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,   0, 166, 213,   0,   0,   0, 175, 255, 235,   4,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0,  16, 247, 122,   0,   0,   0,  88, 255, 255,  71,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0, 105, 255, 192, 171, 171, 171, 182, 255, 255, 159,   0,   0,   0,
  0,   0, 203, 215, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 196, 255, 239,   6,   0,   0,
  0,  44, 255, 108,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  75, 255, 255,  77,   0,   0,
  0, 142, 252,  22,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   5, 238, 255, 164,   0,   0,
  5, 234, 184,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 156, 255, 242,   8,   0,
 81, 255,  95,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  68, 255, 255,  86,   0,
179, 249,  14,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   3, 245, 255, 195,   0
};

[[noreturn]] inline void throw_error(const char* desc, const char* sdl_err)
{
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string(desc) + sdl_err);
}

void update_pixels(
    SDL_Texture& texture,
    const SDL_Rect& texture_rect,
    const unsigned char* src_alpha,
    int src_size_x,
    int src_size_y)
{
    void* pixels;
    int pitch;
    if (SDL_LockTexture(&texture, &texture_rect, &pixels, &pitch))
        throw_error("could not lock texture: ", SDL_GetError());

    auto pixel_buffer = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pixels);
    for (int y = 0; y < src_size_y; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < src_size_x; ++x) {
            // this assumes SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888
            unsigned char* const rgba = pixel_buffer + x * 4;
            unsigned char& r = rgba[0];
            unsigned char& g = rgba[1];
            unsigned char& b = rgba[2];
            unsigned char& a = rgba[3];
            r = 0xff;
            g = 0xff;
            b = 0xff;
            a = src_alpha[x];
        }

        src_alpha += src_size_y;
        pixel_buffer += pitch;
    }

    SDL_UnlockTexture(&texture);
}

int main(int /* argc */, char* /* argv */[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        throw_error("could not init SDL: ", SDL_GetError());

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            1024, 768,
            SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    if (!window)
        throw_error("could not create window: ", SDL_GetError());

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (!renderer)
        throw_error("could not create renderer: ", SDL_GetError());

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 512, 512);
    if (!texture)
        throw_error("could not create texture: ", SDL_GetError());

    SDL_SetTextureColorMod(texture, 255, 0, 0);

    SDL_Rect src_rect;
    src_rect.x = 0;
    src_rect.y = 0;
    src_rect.w = 15;
    src_rect.h = 17;
    update_pixels(*texture, src_rect, pixels, src_rect.w, src_rect.h);

    /*
     * FreeType documentation: For optimal rendering on a screen the bitmap should be used as
     * an alpha channel in linear blending with gamma correction.
     *
     * The blending used is therefore:
     * dstRGB = (srcRGB * srcA) + (dstRGB * (1 - srcA))
     * dstA = (srcA * 0) + (dstA * 1) = dstA
     */
    SDL_BlendMode blend_mode = SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode(
        SDL_BLENDFACTOR_SRC_ALPHA, SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, SDL_BLENDOPERATION_ADD,
        SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ZERO, SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE, SDL_BLENDOPERATION_ADD);

    if (SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, blend_mode))
        throw_error("could not set texture blending: ", SDL_GetError());

    while (true) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_Rect dst_rect;
        dst_rect.x = 100;
        dst_rect.y = 100;
        dst_rect.w = src_rect.w;
        dst_rect.h = src_rect.h;
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &src_rect, &dst_rect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_Delay(16);

        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_KEYUP:
                    switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                            return 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected result: red letter "A" on yellow background.

Actual result: malformed red lines inside black square on yellow background. [image: actual result]

I suspect that lines are broken because there is a bug within pointer arithmetics inside `update_pixels` but I have no idea what's causing the black square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, part of this stuff is already done in SDL_ttf library. You could use it to rasterise glyphs to surfaces or generate multichar text surface.

Your `src_alpha += src_size_y;` is incorrect - you copy row by row, but skip by column length, not row length. It should be `src_size_x`. That results in incorrect offset on each row and only first row of your copied image is correct.

Your colour packing when writing to texture is backwards. See https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormatEnum#order - `Packed component order (high bit -> low bit): SDL_PACKEDORDER_RGBA`, meaning `R` is packed at highest bits while `A` is at lowest. So, when representing it with `unsigned char*`, First byte is `A` and fourth is `R`:

```
        unsigned char& r = rgba[3];
        unsigned char& g = rgba[2];
        unsigned char& b = rgba[1];
        unsigned char& a = rgba[0];
```

You don't need custom blending, use `SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND`, that is 'standard' "src-alpha, one-minus-src-alpha" formula everyone uses (note that it does not blend dst alpha channel itself, nor uses it to any extent; when blending, we only care about src alpha).

Finally one more approach to this: you could put your glyph luminance value (alpha, whatever it is called, the point is it only have one channel) and put it into **every** channel. That way you could do additive blending without using alpha at all, don't even need RGBA texture. Glyph colour could still be multiplied with colour mod. SDL_ttf implements just that.

Comment: To clarify RGBA order - there is RGBA8888 and ABGR8888, but e.g. my CPU is little endian so it is backwards due to 'little' bits are at the 'end'. You could use `RGBA32` which adapts to endianess of target platform to have R at first byte.

Comment: "part of this stuff is already done in SDL_ttf library. You could use it to rasterise glyphs to surfaces or generate multichar text surface" this is exactly the problem. I want textures, not surfaces. I want a spritesheet of glyphs, not surface. Plus SDL_ttf has no support for dynamically adding required glyphs to the atlas. I have read numerous times that SDL_ttf uses CPU instead of GPU which makes it inefficient.

Comment: For the bit packing - I reversed the order and now it works. Is this the best multiplatform implementation? Is now the corrected code endian-dependent? I don't really get why SDL uses reverse bit order for letters in their color packing enums.

Comment: "the point is it only have one channel) and put it into every channel. That way you could do additive blending without using alpha at all, don't even need RGBA texture" Would additive blending work with e.g. red text (255, 0, 0) on yellow background (255, 255, 0)? If I additively blend red with yellow I get yellow because yellow is already full of red component. I have tried additing blending before and red text on yellow background was not visible.

Comment: "note that it does not blend dst alpha channel itself, nor uses it to any extent; when blending, we only care about src alpha" Is the documentation then wrong? For `SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND` https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureBlendMode says `dstA = srcA + (dstA * (1-srcA))` but I don't want to affect dstA at all.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, additive would only work for white font, haven't thought about it enough. As for endianess - no, if you want in-memory order to always be RGBA then use RGBA32 format (which is alias for RGB8888 or ABGR8888 depending on endianess).

Comment: As for SDL_ttf - you can easily copy resulting surface into textue atlas. Of course font rendering is more complicated than that if you want to account for kerning and other things.

Comment: "font rendering is more complicated than that if you want to account for kerning and other things". Yes, that's exactly why I'm trying my own implementation. SDL_ttf is kind of a closed box that has quite inflexible API. This makes it hard or impossible to use if I want more granularity. And the library isn't that big either (~4k LOC) so I think it will be valuable experience for me to try make something more suited for my project.